# replace empties with 2 bones armature in script

Tags: bones, vertices, parent

The following is a script that adds empties to vertices.  Each empty is parented to a vertex.  Since I know nothing of scripting would it be easy to replace the empties with a 2 boned armature that I created?  It needs to be duplicated each time instead of being added.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
obj = context.edit_object
mesh = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
empties = []
# selected verts
for v in [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]:
    empty = bpy.data.objects.new("Empty", None)
    empty.parent = obj
    empty.parent_type = 'VERTEX'
    empty.parent_vertices = [v.index] * 3
    scene.objects.link(empty)
    empty.matrix_parent_inverse.identity()
    empties.append((v.index, empty))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved adding one line and changing another(variables changed so it makes sense):

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
obj = context.edit_object
mesh = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
armature =bpy.data.objects['Armature'] #added this line to get armature object
armatures = []
# selected verts
for v in [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]:
    bones = armature.copy() # changed this line to mke copies
    bones.parent = obj
    bones.parent_type = 'VERTEX'
    bones.parent_vertices = [v.index] * 3
    scene.objects.link(bones)
    bones.matrix_parent_inverse.identity()
    armatures.append((v.index, bones))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but i realized i have a problem, the bones have a location of 0,0,0 i need it to have the location of the vertex, can this be done??

Answer (score 0):

I joined the bones, and apply armature that gave the world position in edit mode.

```
bpy.ops.object.select_grouped(type='TYPE')
bpy.ops.object.join()
bpy.ops.object.posemode_toggle()
bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
bpy.ops.pose.armature_apply()
bpy.ops.object.posemode_toggle()
```